Data Management API - Filter to exclude an item from folder content search
I have been using filters like filter[lastModifiedTimeRollup]-ge and filter[lastModifiedTimeRollup]-le to target only files within a specific range using the documentation.
Does APS support filters for "not equal" or "not contains" conditions?
Ideally, I am looking for a filter that allows me to exclude certain items. For instance, I would like to use a filter like this:
/data/v1/projects/{{projectId}}/folders/{{folderId}}/contents?filter[type]=items&filter[attributes.displayName]-ne=ONC-PRN-3710-SWS-TTA-DES-MDR-80001.dwg
I couldn’t find an equivalent filter in the API documentation.Tried -ne, -neq and <>
